# Run code when getter/setting changed

Tags: javascript

Can I use getter/setters to do a similar task to an observer?

So for example if I assign an instance of a getter/setter to multiple objects, these will all be references, so if either object causes the getter to change the same code would run right?

I have tried the following code:

```
var obj = {
  value: null,
  get val() {
    return this.value;
  },
  set val(x) {
    console.log('set');
    if (this.value !== x) {
      console.log('value has been changed, do stuff!');
    }
    this.value = x;
  }
}
var one = {
  name: 'object 1',
  value: obj /* Reference object */
}
var two = {
  name: 'object 2',
  value: obj /* Reference object */
}
var three = {
  name: 'object 3',
  value: obj /* Reference object */
}
```

Then run `one.value.value = 2` which should fire the console log. However I just get `2` output in the console and no console.log.

**Edit**

Just saw where I was going wrong, I should be doing `one.value.val = 2`, this is starting to work, hang on.

**Edit 2**

Not too sure if this will function the way i'm expecting. I'm going to try and breakdown what i'm trying to do.

I have got an array of objects as follows:

```
var images = [ 
  { index: 0, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 1, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 2, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 3, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 4, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 5, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String },
  { index: 6, object: HTMLElement, src: String, active: Object, alt: String } 
];
```

This object will get duplicated a couple of times throughout my script however the active state needs to remain the same throughout all instances.

How i'm duplicating the object:

```
var newList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < _.images.length; i++) {
   // Create new instances of the images
   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.src = images[i].object.src;
   img.classList.add('responsive-img');
   img.alt = images[i].alt;

   var span = document.createElement('span');
   span.appendChild(img);

   if (i === current) img.parentNode.classList.add('active');

   var newImage = {
      object: img,
      index: i,
      src: images[i].src,
      active: images[i].active, // Use reference to old list
      alt: images[i].alt
   };
   newList.push(newImage);

   // Add each image to the gallery DOM
   _.gallery.main.appendChild(span);
}
```

Basically now what I need to happen, is that if the `active` value is changed in either reference, then code should execute and add/remove a class from the `object` within that instance.

Does this make sense?

So if the following is run

```
images[0].active.val = 1
```

Then `newList[0].object.classList.Add('active');` and `images[0].object.classList.Add('active');` executes.

There is more code that should execute however lets take it a step at a time. I was using a Polyfill for Observer before however it's too heavy weight for what i want to do and over the top, also having issues with it on Internet Explorer.

I think the best way to do this is maybe some kind of callback from the `setter` so I could run unique code for each instance that this object is within?

Comment: Well did you try it out?

Comment: problem here is that if you change one.value, it will change also two.value and three.value. If that is your intent, should work

Comment: I have tried it yes however it doesn't appear to be displaying the console.log's. And yes @juvian that's my intent.

Comment: are you able to debug to see whether it's reaching your `if` statement and if so, whether or not the `if` statement is executing as intended?

Comment: @AGE see update

Comment: Well, your setter is for val not value, one.value.val = 2 does run the code

Comment: Delete your first example. Having the same example multiple times is just confusing and distracting

Comment: Not sure if this is going to function how i'm intending, let me writeup a more detailed example of what I need.

Comment: @juvian see updated post

Comment: @AGE see updated post

Comment: Well, active will be same object across all instances so would work. Still, you have no way to access your image object from the setter unless you add a active.image variable to reference your image object

Comment: @juvian is there a way I can add some kind of callback, or pass in a function so that I can reference a different image if the reference to the active state is within a different object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels a bit hackish but adding a getter to active to set the object you are referring should work :

```js
var active = {
 _value : null,
  object : null,
  set value(v) {
   _value = v;
    this.object.style.display = v;
  }
}

var images = [
  {img : document.querySelector('.div1'), _active : active, get active () {this._active.object = this.img; return this._active}
  },
  {img : document.querySelector('.div2'), _active : active, get active () {this._active.object = this.img; return this._active}
  }
]

images[0].active.value = 'none';
images[1].active.value = 'block';
```

```html
<div class = 'div1'>div 1</div>
<div class = 'div2' style = 'display:none'>div 2</div>
```